# Command line adding a printer with duplex and fax enabled

Tags: windows-server-2003, scripting, printer, windows-xp

We have an OCE Imagistics cm2520 unit, a big copier that does fax and duplex printing.  Currently I'm trying to have our XP workstations print without using a Windows print server, but just using the copier's built-in print server.

From [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q189105) and others I managed to get a batch file to add the printer:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /b "Office Copier" /x /n "Office Copier" /if /f "S:\IT Install\OCE driver\Win2003_PCL\GSRH3.INF" /l"S:\IT Install\OCE driver\Win2003_PCL" /r "IP_192.168.1.200" /m "Generic 25C-1/25C-1P PCL"
```

However, duplex and fax are disabled/greyed out when you go to print.  Before when I had a W2k3 server as the print server, they were enabled.

How can I script it to add the printer with them already enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/82210789-81dc-41d0-a073-ca881fe20eca/printer-device-settings-wmi-dll-etc) also suggested a registry hack, which worked.  I did a compare using TextPad on the before and after of the registry branch.  Then I had to [save as ANSI](https://superuser.com/questions/641452/you-can-only-import-binary-registry-files-from-within-the-registry-editor) rather than Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/2kprintcontrol.php), which has a typo (it should be PrintUIEntry on both /Ss and /Sr) shows you can set and restore settings files.  So you can set up the printer how you like, save the settings with /Ss, and then restore them with your batch file after adding the printer:

```
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Ss /n "printer" /a "file.dat"
```

and then:

```
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Sr /n "printer" /a "file.dat"
```

However, for some reason the latter one gives me an error:

---

### Printers

### Operation could not be completed.

### OK

And does not change the settings.  But it seems like a potential solution at least...